# How do you connect a bot to a voice channel?

Tags: discord.py

How do I make a bot join a voice channel in rewrite?
Anything I try doesn't work, and it doesn't give an error either.
Below are my attempts:

```
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
```

```
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(ctx.author.voice.channel.id)
    await channel.connect()
```

Edit: I turned off the error handler and now I get this error:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'`

Edit 2: I am in a voice channel that the bot can connect to. ctx.author.voice_channel doesn't work, I get this this error:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'`

Edit 3: The command works. I installed PyNaCl and it works just fine.

Comment: These should work, assuming the person calling the command is in a voice channel.  Make sure that any error handlers you have are re-raising any unhandled errois.

Comment: It shouldn't be voice.channel but voice_channel, also make it under a try:  just in case the command sender is not in a  voice channel at that moment.
.

What you tried doing is getting a channel attribute from ctx.author.voice which is None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these code.

```
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```